# Sum from a third table based on 2 different set of conditions

Tags: excel

I am trying to Sum in B2 the Total from Table 2 for each field called "Pommes" in table 1.
Once the "Fruit" being "Pommes" condition is validated in Table 1, we need to sum the column "Total" in Table 2 if Cat 1 and Cat 2 are equal. 
I was able to make it happen by adding a column which I called "Total" in table 1 to Table 1 with the following formula:
=SUMPRODUCT((Table2[Produit]=[@Produit])*(Table2[Variante]=[@Variante])*Table2[Prix final])

and then using the following in B2:
=SUMPRODUCT((Table1[Fruit]=A2)*Table1[[Total]:[Total]])

Is there a way to make this happen WITHOUT adding that column in Table 1 and refer directly to Table 2?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following formula should work, note it has to be entered as an array formula, ie instead of pressing Enter, do Ctrl + Shift + Enter

`=SUMPRODUCT((IF(Table1[Fruit]=A1,SUMIFS(Table2[Final Prix],Table2[Produit],Table1[Produit],Table2[Variante],Table1[Variante]),0)))`

Couple of examples with the data you provided

[image]
[image]
[image]